# How to build a working r/c crane capable of lifting 2 lbs/1Kg

Tags: rcservo

Building an r/c crane capable of lifting and rotating 2.2 lbs. Have constructed the crane with a base on a ball bearing lazy-susan for rotation of 90 degrees. The question is: how to attach the crane base (2.38"OD plastic pipe) to a servo for rotation control.
Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the lazy-susan rotating base be a gear, and then you can have a smaller gear coupled with it and the servo run the gear in a vertical orientation. The following figure should give you an idea of what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ln_r1 ideas is very good, but I prefer the gear is on lazy susan side. So the motor is in vertical shaft position.

Because getting gear at lazy susan periphery is not easy, alternatively you can install a large gear below lazy susan (common shaft with lazy susan).

More easy, use pulley. Either lazy susan rim as pulley or install large pulley below lazy susan (common shaft with lazy susan).